# I get "Connection refused" when i try to use WebGoat

Tags: web, localhost, port

I try to run WebScarab and when I try to connect to "localhost/webgoat/attac"
I get next message

```
WebScarab encountered an error trying to retrieve

GET http://localhost:80/webgoat/attac HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

The error was :

Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.owasp.webscarab.httpclient.URLFetcher.connect(URLFetcher.java:412)
at org.owasp.webscarab.httpclient.URLFetcher.fetchResponse(URLFetcher.java:229)
at org.owasp.webscarab.plugin.proxy.RevealHidden$Plugin.fetchResponse(RevealHidden.java:100)
at org.owasp.webscarab.plugin.proxy.ManualEdit$Plugin.fetchResponse(ManualEdit.java:243)
at org.owasp.webscarab.plugin.proxy.ConnectionHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:233)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I was tried to run WebScarab  on Ubuntu 13.04 and windows 7.
I disabled all antiviruses and firewalls before.

I have no idea what to do?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure WebGoat is running, firstly, and listening on port 80? WebScarab will give the message above if it is unable to connect to the site that you have instructed it to.

Is it possible that you are running WebScarab and WebGoat in different virtual machines? If so, localhost on one VM is NOT the same as localhost on another VM.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the proxy in WebScarab (Tools->Proxies), 127.0.0.1:3128 is the default value. You must change this and try again. I needed restart the app.

Good luck!!